# Changing github commit author info

Tags: git, github, git-filter-branch

GitHub made changes recently to stop using some generic domains that meant that the dummy email address I was using for commits (to keep my actual email address private) was no longer correct to have contributions counted.

The help at GitHub told me to use the this https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info on lmy local clone to change the author info for previous commits, which I duly did in the Git Bash... which went through the rewrite, and informed me that `Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten.

What now? Do I commit/push? There are no changes showing in the repository and the Github repo hasnt changed....

Comment: If you run `git log` do the commits contain the new email?

Comment: is this your project only, or is it a public project?

Comment: @PeterFoti Yes the emails are changed.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady It's public https://github.com/wolf99/SCPI_Build

Comment: You should understand that by this change your branch is no longer a fast-forward commit, and to push it you need to overwrite the whole remote branch ( or at least since the oldest commit that contained your old email ), if you run some visual tool like `gitk` you'll see. how many changed commits does `git status` report ?

Comment: OK, my branch has 241 and the origin/master has 240. Should I `pull` to fix or would that overwrite the author changes?

Comment: So I ran the script, did a `git pull` then `git push` and that seems to have worked as intended. As noted at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16900329/1292918 there is a backup copy of the history in refs/original kept that can be got rid of after the exercise is complete.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady If you would like to make your comment an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: this somehow isn't logical to me, how many commits do you have now after pulling ?

Comment: I just checked and as I expected, your commits number was doubled, your old commits still exist, are you fine with keeping them ?

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady What should I do to get rid of the old commits?

Comment: well if you don't care about your history, I think you should force push and overwrite the tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Force push was the answer so, as indicated by @MohammadAbuShady

Answer (score 0):

Create a new branch and execute this command line (take care with this command, read more here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch):

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='your name'; GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='your_email@mail.com'; GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='your name'; GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='your_email@mail.com';" HEAD
```

After that, publish the new branch and if you need, change the new branch as the main branch (if you are lonely in the project).