# Separate Git Repository for team, push changes to another repo as 1 account

Tags: git

I'm working on a contract for a company that has their own git repository.  I'd like to allow my team to work on the project, and then push all changes to the company repository all under one account (no history from other team members).  Is this possible?  Or am I stuck manually copying the files over into the directory and committing the changes?

Answer (score 0):

> then push all changes to the company repository all under one account

Yes, if you create (each time you want to push back) a new repo from a [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) applied to your current repo (with commits from multiple collaborator)

[A filter-branch will be able to rewrite the committer and author information](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/) in order to rewrite the repo as one done by only one user.
[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10908872/6309) as an example.

Make sure to try and [preserve the commit date as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11179245/6309).